# Triggering AWS Glue Workflow through Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am new to AWS GLUE and trying to trigger Glue workflow using the Lambda function.

I am using the attribute `boto3.client('glue')` but I am getting an error saying :

> Glue' object has no attribute `start_workflow_run`

Here is the piece of code that I am trying to run:

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('glue')
client.start_workflow_run(Name = 'Workflow_New', Arguments = {})
```

Is there any other method by what I can achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: The other responses are wrong. They keep giving advice on running jobs, not the workflow.It is simply that boto3 version was not the latest version in the python runtime. I would expect it to be now (it is on boto3-1.12.22). If not, use a lambda layer with newer boto3 version,

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this SO on how to call AWS Glue from a lambda, with code snippet.

[How to Trigger Glue ETL Pyspark job through S3 Events or AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652485/how-to-trigger-glue-etl-pyspark-job-through-s3-events-or-aws-lambda/57655429#57655429)

```
import boto3
print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    glue = boto3.client('glue')
    gluejobname = "YOUR GLUE JOB NAME"

    try:
        runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)
        status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=gluejobname, RunId=runId['JobRunId'])
        print("Job Status : ", status['JobRun']['JobRunState'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist '
              'and your bucket is in the same region as this '
              'function.'.format(source_bucket, source_bucket))
    raise e
```

Thanks

Yuva

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I was able to trigger a Glue job from Lambda, the issue was only with the Workflows.

Comment: ok, i thought otherwise. Per this link there is boto3 api command for glue run_workflow, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.start_workflow_run.  I havent tried yet, will update u.

Comment: Yes, there is an API mentioned in the boto3 documentation:  __start_workflow_run__
But not sure why this one is not working.

Answer (score 1):

this works to invoke a glue **workflow** from Lambda (python):

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # add your region_name
    glue = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name='eu-west-2') 
    
    # only 'Name' parameter
    workflow_run_id = glue.start_workflow_run(Name = 'Your_Workflow')

    print(f'workflow_run_id: {workflow_run_id}')
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-dg.pdf
[image: AWS Glue Developer Guide]

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the below code snippet:

```py
import boto3

glueClient = boto3.client('glue')

response = glueClient.start_workflow_run(Name = 'wf_name')
```

You can use also this documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.start_workflow_run

Answer (score 0):

Following link  you can find aws example and pass parameter for glue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html

[AWS Glue -- Access Workflow Parameters from Within Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825003/aws-glue-access-workflow-parameters-from-within-job)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I checked those links but this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that glue has function named 'start_workflow_run'. Please try 'start_job_run'

response = client.start_job_run(JobName = 'Workflow_New', Arguments = {} )

Comment: This did not work as __start_job_run__ will search for the Glue job names not workflow names

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    glueClient = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-west-2')
    response = glueClient.start_workflow_run(Name=Workflow_name)
```

Also, I think you might want to add error handling around the response as well!